# Scikit-Learn LinearRegression: Calculate predictions from coef and intercept

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

After I trained a LinearRegression model, how do I relate the `coef` and `intercept` to my `predict` result?

Data set I'm using:
https://github.com/selva86/datasets/blob/master/BostonHousing.csv

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import metrics
housing_dataset = pd.read_csv("BostonHousing.csv")
X = housing_dataset.drop(["medv"], axis = 1)
y = housing_dataset.filter(["medv"], axis = 1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
house_predictor = LinearRegression()
house_predictor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = house_predictor.predict(X_test)
```

Then I checked the `coef` and `intercept_`

```
coef = house_predictor.coef_
intercept = house_predictor.intercept_
data = [0] * len(X_test)
for i in range(0,12):
    t = X_test.iloc[:,i] * coef[0][i]
    data += t
data += intercept
```

My understanding is the coef refers to the impact factor of each column to the price

which means: `medv = crim*coef[0] + zn*coef[1]...lstat*coef[12] + intercept`

But then I put all three columns together, for the test data set:

```
comparison_df = pd.DataFrame( data=[y_test.medv.values,[ x[0] for x in y_pred],
                                    data.values
                                   
                                   ]
                              
                            ).T 

comparison_df.columns = ["Actual", "Predict", "calc"]
```

I would expect the field "predict" is the same as "Calc"

But this is what I get

```
Actual  Predict calc
0   23.6    28.996724   33.594209
1   32.4    36.025565   37.820822
2   13.6    14.816944   24.006830
3   22.8    25.031979   27.839293
4   16.1    18.769880   27.552908
... ... ... ...
97  17.9    -0.164237   17.315363
98  9.6 13.684867   22.864581
99  17.2    16.183597   26.975483
100 22.5    22.276220   28.816449
101 21.4    24.479024   29.025652
```

Which is way too far from the accuracy.

Can someone shed some lights?

Comment: Your approach is correct, there is only a small bug in the code as you are calculating the predictions using the first 12 columns of `X_test`, but `X_test` has 13 columns.

Comment: To Flavia's point, remember that `range` _excludes_ the upper bound.  (Also the lower bound defaults to 0, so `range(X_test.shape[1])` would work fine and be a little clearer.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Flavia Giammarino and @Ben Reiniger! Yes after I changed the range from 0-13!

To summary:

- If you have n features(n columns in your data set) as F1, F2...Fn
  and 1 label, after the linerRegression model is built, you get a
  coef as a coef as an ndarray, shape (1, n), as [c1, c2...cn)
- The predicted value will be: c1 * F1 + c2 * F2...cn * Fn +
  model.intercept_
- Example in sklearn website:
  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html